# Facebook Share Graph Object not working if adding image

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I am trying to share a graphobject on facebook but i'm encountering some problems when i add the image.

Here is my current code:

```
    // Construct an FBSDKSharePhoto
UIImage* psImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fb_share_logo"];
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = psImg;
photo.userGenerated = NO;

NSDictionary *properties = @{@"og:type": @"my_obj",
                             @"og:title": @"Title",
                             @"og:description": @"Description",
                             @"og:web": @"http://www.mywebssite.com"
//                           @"og:image": @[photo]
                             };

//create GraphObject from properties
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

//create action
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction actionWithType:@"my_action" object:object key:@"my_key"];

//create content
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent new];

//set content action
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"my_prop_type";

FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
shareDialog.fromViewController = self;
shareDialog.shareContent = content;
if (![shareDialog canShow]) {
    // update the app UI accordingly
    NSLog(@"is showing");
}
NSError *error;
if (![shareDialog validateWithError:&error]) {
    // check the error for explanation of invalid content
    NSLog(@"error");
}

if([shareDialog canShow]){
    [shareDialog show];
}
```

If i don't add the image it works and the dialog shows but i need it. If i add the image i get this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode parameter for shareDialog is not set in your code.

So first of all you need to set it as follows ([more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33152056)):

```
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative; // to open native app
    if (![dialog canShow]) {
        // if there is no FB app installed on that device, use browser
        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser;
}
```

And if you still cannot open the share dialog, you should check your Info.plist file for LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key and see if it set as follows ([developers.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9#whitelistapp)):

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>    
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    </array>
```