# Facebook Cordova plugin - sharing a photo (with no link) results in empty Share Dialog

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, meteor

I'm using the cordova Facebook plugin (https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) in a Meteor mobile app on Android.

I can successfully use the Share Dialog to share a photo with a link (as in the plugin example here: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4#show-a-dialog). I.e...

```
{
  method: "share",
  href: "http://example.com",
  caption: "Such caption, very feed.",
  description: "Much description",
  picture: 'http://example.com/image.png'
}
```

However, if I attempt to share a *photo-only* (i.e. with *no* website link)...

```
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog({
  method: "share",
  picture:'https://www.google.co.jp/logos/doodles/2014/doodle-4-google-2014-japan-winner-5109465267306496.2-hp.png',
  name:'Test Post',
  message:'First photo post',
  caption: 'Testing using phonegap plugin',
  description: 'Posting photo using phonegap facebook plugin'
}, function (response) {
  console.log(response)
}, function (response) {
  console.log(response)
});
```

....the Share Dialog opens, but is empty.

This is *exactly* as per the final example given on the plugin's github (https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4#publish-a-photo) so I assume it's a valid use-case.

Any ideas?

Comment: is your device having native facebook app in it ?

Comment: Yes. It has the app. The dialog opens.... it's just empty.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this:

1. https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/36
2. [Facebook share content only shares URL in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148544/facebook-share-content-only-shares-url-in-ios-9/33152056#33152056)
3. https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/221

and if it still not solved your problem then there is official open issue with this plugin you will need to change the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the method to be "feed" instead of "share" if no link is provided.

Change:

```
 method: "share",
```

To:

```
 method: "feed",
```

Comment: Result is the same whether the method is _share_ or _feed_ - dialog opens, but is completely empty.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and finally got it resolved! How? I just did this:

```
method: "share",
href: 'url_of_image_or_photo_to_share'
```

Even after doing it this way, the share dialog was showing like a link or small icon! So I went ahead and hit the Post but and saw it like I would expect on Facebook.

Give it a trial!

Answer (score 0):

**1. untrusted ssl cert for https image url**

If the certificate isn't trusted by facebook, it won't preview the image. See https://rameerez.com/facebook-sharing-not-scraping-url-correctly-with-https-links/

**2. image has not been cached by facebook**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/

> Pre-caching images
>
> When content is shared for the first time, the Facebook crawler will
> scrape and cache the metadata from the URL shared. The crawler has to
> see an image at least once before it can be rendered. This means that
> the first person who shares a piece of content won't see a rendered
> image:

[image]

To verify whether this is the problem, use the facebook Sharing Debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/