# Share image to Facebook using Cordova SocialSharing plugin with link attached

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using SocialSharing Plugin for cordova, to allow my Android App to share an image directly to user's news feed.

I have read all the documentation and found no way to make it share like this app does. I don´t know what language they used to build it, but the share dialog looks exactly the same, except that the published image to the user's news feed has a small link on top of it.

Is there any plugin for Cordova, that allow sharing this way to Facebook?

Thank you very much.

[image: this is how the app share. It adds a small link to the top]

Comment: I am not sure.... But as per my knowledge you have to make an application project in facebook and link to your app. May be it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of cordova-plugin-facebook-connect. The option to include photos in a share dialog will be added in the next release:

https://github.com/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/issues/54

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently investigating this too as the Social Sharing plugin doesn't link to your own Facebook App as far as I can tell.

I haven't tried it yet, but it appears that this plugin is what we need, and I'm hoping to investigate further in the next few weeks:

https://github.com/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect

This SO thread also seems relevant and references the old version of the Facebook plugin that the one linked above was forked from:

[Facebook Cordova plugin - sharing a photo (with no link) results in empty Share Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730145/facebook-cordova-plugin-sharing-a-photo-with-no-link-results-in-empty-share)

Hope this is useful!

Comment: Hi. It seems that the "cordova-plugin-facebook-connect" is outdated and does not includes the feature to allow sharing an image file. I tried it and when sharing something 
 the link to the app is added to the facebook, like on the Image I put on my post.